# How to override Runnable inside a method?

Tags: java, overriding, actionlistener, extend

Please, give me an advice for following question.

I have class A & class B
How to override Runnable inside a method foo in class B?

```
class A {    
    //some code
    .......    
    protected void foo() {
        //some code
        .......         
        //adding click listener to instance of MyButton
        myButton.show(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                .......
            }
        });         
        //some code
        .......
    }    
    //some code
    .......    
}

class B extends A {    
    @Override
    protected void foo() {
        super.foo();            
        //some NEW code
        .......         
        //adding click listener to instance of MyButton
        myButton.show(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Copied&Pasted old code
                .......                 
                //NEW code
                .......
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Can I add new code to button's handler (Runnable in myButton) without copying&pasting existing code from super? How?

Comment: what's access specifier of mybutton ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use named class instances instead of anonymous class instances if you want to re-use the logic.

For example :

```
class A {
    ...
    static class ButtonLogic implements Runnable
    {
        public void run() {...}
    }

    protected void foo() {
        //adding click listener to instance of MyButton
        myButton.show(new A.ButtonLogic());
            .......
    }
}
```

Then B can override that logic :

```
class B extends A {

    @Override
    protected void foo() {
        super.foo();

        //some NEW code
        .......

        //adding click listener to instance of MyButton
        myButton.show(new A.ButtonLogic(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                .......

                //NEW code
                .......
            }
        });


    }

}
```

Comment: @Anton In that case, you can't override that Runnable.